# Node.js - what happens if I call response.end while I/O and callbacks are still running?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, what happens if call "response.end()" while my I/O calls and/or callbacks are still executing? As in the following:

```
var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    fs.writeFile('baz', 'contents', function() {
                  myOtherFunc();
                  response.end('Second response.end'); 
    }); 

   response.end('First response.end');
});
```

Specifically:

1. Is the HTTP connection freed up immediately upon calling the first response.end? (Bonus points: how can I inspect this myself?)
2. Can I use this to perform arbitrarily complex/costly computation, even synchronous ones, within myOtherFunc? Since the connection has been freed the client is no longer waiting? (Or is there any reason why not?)
3. Can this be used as a paradigm to perform 'background' tasks upon invocation, with 'myOtherFunc' being an arbitrary background task -- since it is essentially now running "in the background"?

Comment: Have you just tried it? I'd expect it to throw an error when trying to write to an already closed stream.

Comment: I did try, it seems to work fine. But I can remove the second response.end(); the questions remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested, but:

1. Given the asynchronous nature of node, it's possible the stream wouldn't be freed up before the second `response.end` is called, but I doubt you can rely on that... at some point the connection must close and trying to send new data will "at best" fail silently.
2. The connection is freed and the client won't be waiting... for that request, at least, but costly synchronous computations will hold up the rest of your application, full stop.  Any subsequent requests will have to wait for your work to finish, and odds are `response` will be gone if you don't get to it by the next few ticks.
3. Learn more about node's single threadedness.  node works not by doing a bunch of things at once, but by not blocking while it's waiting.  There is no "background" unless you explicitly spawn your own thread to do something.

Edit: I'm working with the assumption that the `response` stream is closed explicitly, with the `end` call, rather than just sitting out there waiting to be garbage collected. My assumption is it's just done asynchronously rather than waiting on completion to continue on, and if you get there within the next couple ticks of the event loop, it may still be allocated.

Edit Again: Your intrepid answerer has searched tirelessly through the node source and confirmed that, indeed, two calls to `end` should indeed not work, the second should be short circuited [by the `OutgoingMessage.finished` property (see lines 499-501 and 541)](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/2eddd7411234bf633df6a7bdb9c120ed89853324/lib/_http_outgoing.js)

Comment: 1. So re: your link, this means answer to #1 is 'yes', the first reponse.end ends the connection? 

2. Super. So changing the focus of the question - suppose I remove the second remove.end(), can I now use this 'background' (background in the sense that the requesting client is gone) task 'freely', while understanding that it's in the single-thread context, but with the ability to run further non-blocking I/O operations? 

Assuming my heavy operations are I/O, I can use this paradigm (running response.end() outside the callbacks) to delegate tasks to being run *after* the request has ended?

Comment: I kept looking and didn't see an explicit releasing of the stream, but I was looking for all of 20 minutes, I can't give a definitive answer based on what I saw but regardless, calling `end` explicitly sets a `finished` property that stops that stream from being usable through normal channels.  You should be able to test fairly easily by just doing something time intensive in the callback and seeing if the client finishes loading before the server is finished processing.  For your changed focus, see the next comment.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, then yes, you can use a callback to run tasks after the request has ended.  Usually that will be done with a call to `setImmediate` or an otherwise appropriate variant that calls code in some subsequent pass through the event loop (if you don't have a legitimately occurring asynchronous action like `fs.writeFile` already that you want to run your process after it completes).  The client will not wait for the callback to complete, just `end` the response and don't mess with the response in your callback.

Comment: Thanks, accepted. Would(n't) this be a great way to handle requests which initiate heavy background operations? I could free the client (and the response) saying "I'll handle this later", then delegate the action to the I/O+callbacks (which are run after the response). Would doing this across many requests pose any scaling issue? (Why?)

(already marked as accepted, would appreciate any input anyway :)

Comment: The issue isn't so much scaling as communication.  HTTP communication must be initiated by the client, so if you finish your response to the client and then finish your processing later, you've got no way to send that information back to the client.

This is typically handled instead by [long polling](http://blog.nemikor.com/2010/05/21/long-polling-in-nodejs/), where the client makes an ajax request after the page has loaded and just waits for the response.  You want to avoid long polling in apache, but node works very well for it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling response.end doesn't stop any asynchronous code that's still executing.  You'll might see weird behavior though if you try to end or modify a response that's already been ended. So, basically yes to all.  I'll admit though, I'm not an expert on how node handles its HTTP connections behind the scenes.